# Nvidia-settings problem

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

When I try to change resolution using nvidia-settings I get following error:

[image]

How can I downgrade nvidia-settings without messing up my drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your driver instead.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That command does the following.

- Adds the “Ubuntu-X” team to PPA to your configuration. See more
  information on the PPA
  https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates
- Updates the available packages
- Upgrades your current driver to the latest available version which in this case is from newly added PPA.

Comment: Can you add information on *why* and *how* this works?

Comment: I don't want to mess up my drivers, I have really bad experience with this, I prefer my drivers to be installed automatically.

Comment: I use Nvidia GeForce 6100, if I use ppa you provided which drivers will be installed

Comment: Your drivers will be installed automatically with this answer.

Comment: I ran your command and I still have 173.xxx drivers, and still same error as before.

Comment: Unless you really need the old 173 driver use the newer one. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers nvidia-settings`